Angular in kubernetes internal communication is failing
I happen to have a test project that is created in angular 17 and communicates with a python backend.
The thing is that I would like the communication to happen internally through the python service but when I use as host :
this.http.get('http://service-a:5000/message', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(data => this.messageA = data);`

To connect to the back I get an error in the browser ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, I have tried to access the pod with angular and do a wget with the same url
wget -qO- http://service-a:5000/message
Hello from Service A!

It returns correctly the response from the api but when I try to do it from the browser it only throws errors
Does anyone know how I can communicate internally using the service? I leave the deployment.yaml for you to see it.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: frontend-angular:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: frontend
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-a
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-a
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-a
        image: service-a:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: service-a

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-b
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-b
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-b
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-b
        image: service-b:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-b
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: service-b

communicate internally using the service

What happens if your kubectl port-forward service/frontend --namespace=${NAMESPACE} 8080:80 (where NAMEPACE is set the namespace you're using) and then try browsing localhost:8080?

What happens is that I can open my angular application correctly but it does not solve the backend as I say.
The connection is made through the back service. The back pod is service-a and to connect I use the http://service-a:5000/message but it returns ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Does the call succeeds when you try with the standard Kubernetes service URL? Try sending the GET request to http://service-a.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/message

You can't access ClusterIP services from the end user's browser, it's not inside the cluster.  Your code isn't actually running in the Deployment, it's delivering the code to the out-of-cluster browser and the browser isn't actually running it.  You need to set up an Ingress or similar access method for the backend.

So it would only be possible if I communicate with a back with ingress and it communicates internally with another back for example?
